# Copy data file from Xcode to iPad sandbox

Tags: xcode, ios5, testing, ios-simulator

I created an app in Xcode and added a text file for the app to open and display.

How can i get this text file into the iPad sandbox documents directory for testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do:

1. Create a path to your Documents directory
2. Make sure your text file is in your app bundle (Drag/drop into Xcode should be fine)
3. Copy that text file by name from the app bundle to the Documents directory

Try this:

```
// Documents path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Destination path
NSString *fileInDocumentsPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"name-of-your-file.txt"];

// Origin path
NSString *fileInBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"name-of-your-file" ofType:@"txt"];

// File manager for copying
NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:fileInBundlePath toPath:fileInDocumentsPath error:&error];
```

Comment: @Ron, the way to mark a question as answered is to click the green check mark outline. The up/down arrows are for a different function.